# How to get all hrefs(inside <a tag) and assign them to a variable??

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need all hrefs present in 'a' tag and assign it to a variable
I did this, but only got first link

```
soup_level1 = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
userName = soup_level1.find(class_='_32mo')
link1 = (userName.get('href'))
```

And the output i get is

```
print(link1)
https://www.facebook.com/xxxxxx?ref=br_rs
```

But i need atleast top 3 or top 5 links
The structure of webpage is

```
 `<div>
  <a class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx?ref=br_rs">`
  </div>
   <div>
  <a class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/yyyyy?ref=br_rs">`
  </div>
  <div>
  <a class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/zzzzz?ref=br_rs">`
  </div>
```

I need those hrefs

Comment: why is this tagged selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div>
  <a class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx?ref=br_rs">`
  </div>
   <div>
  <a class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/yyyyy?ref=br_rs">`
  </div>
  <div>
  <a class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/zzzzz?ref=br_rs">`
  </div>
  """
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
my_links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "_32mo"})
for link in my_links:
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Output

```
https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx?ref=br_rs
https://www.facebook.com/yyyyy?ref=br_rs
https://www.facebook.com/zzzzz?ref=br_rs
```

To get top n links you can use

```
max_num_of_links=2
for link in my_links[:max_num_of_links]:
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Output

```
https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx?ref=br_rs
https://www.facebook.com/yyyyy?ref=br_rs
```

You can also save the top n links to a list

```
link_list=[]
max_num_of_links=2
for link in my_links[:max_num_of_links]:
    link_list.append(link.get('href'))
print(link_list)
```

Output

```
['https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx?ref=br_rs', 'https://www.facebook.com/yyyyy?ref=br_rs']
```

**EDIT:**

If you need the driver to get the links one by one

```
max_num_of_links=3
for link in my_links[:max_num_of_links]:
        driver.get(link.get('href'))
        # rest of your code ...
```

For some reason if you want it in different variables like link1,link2 etc..

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html="""
<div>
  <a class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/xxxxx?ref=br_rs">`
  </div>
   <div>
  <a class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/yyyyy?ref=br_rs">`
  </div>
  <div>
  <a class="_32mo" href="https://www.facebook.com/zzzzz?ref=br_rs">`
  </div>
  """
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
my_links = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "_32mo"})
link1=my_links[0].get('href')
link2=my_links[1].get('href')
link3=my_links[2].get('href')
# and so on, but be careful here you don't want to try to access a link which is not there or you'll get index error
```

Comment: Thanks! And how can i get the top there links?

Comment: @showrya  max_num_of_links=3. Top three links right?

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can i assign them to a variable, so that i can use them?

Comment: @showrya see the updated answer. I am storing it to a list.

Comment: Sorry! i didn't get it. I'm trying to assign them to a variable(eg. link1). so that i can driver.get(link1)

Comment: I'm getting an error 'Object of type Tag is not JSON serializable'

Comment: I'm trying to assign them to a variable(eg. link1). so that i can driver.get(link1)- I want it in variable so that i can use it again. Thanks!

Comment: @showrya  use  driver.get(link.get('href')). I think this should solve your problem. I've also updated my answer.

Comment: @showrya I have updated my answer so that you can get it into different variables as well

Comment: Thanks for solving it!